# Insert\update data into Central server from multiple servers in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

There are 4 zonal servers and all of them have same table names and table structure. Also, the Central server has to have same table names and table structure. Data from all the 4 servers need to be moved into Central server with only one instance of the table in Central server. i.e, there has to be one set of tables in Central server with data from all the 4 zonal servers. Please suggest any ways to accomplish this task. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read about sunscriptions in SQL Server. It provides different ways to move data between instances using the subscriber-consumer model. You can start [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152578%28v=sql.105%29), for example.

This problem is too wide to give any straight answers, it depeneds on many reasons.